# Grab top 5 rows and combine the rest SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a column for group name and a column for amount spent.
I need to sum the amounts group them based on the group name and then grab the highest five. After that, I need to combine the the rest into it's own group w/ a total of their amount spent.  This is what i have right now

```
SELECT groupName, SUM(amount) AS theAmountSpent
FROM purchases
GROUP BY groupName
ORDER BY theAmountSpent DESC
```

This groups and orders them, but i dont know how to then grab the remaining groups to combine them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should do it:

```
SELECT top 5 groupName, SUM(amount) AS theAmountSpent
into #tempSpent FROM purchases
GROUP BY groupName
ORDER BY theAmountSpent DESC

Select * from #tempSpent -- get the top 5

--get sum for the rest
SELECT SUM(amount) AS theAmountSpent
FROM purchases
where groupName not in (select groupName from #tempSpent)

Drop table #tempSpent
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternate CTE-approach using row_number() (SQL Server 2005+):

```
    WITH cte AS (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SUM(amount)) DESC) AS num, 
        groupName, SUM(amount) AS theAmountSpent
      FROM purchases
      GROUP BY groupName
    )
    SELECT groupName, theAmountSpent FROM cte WHERE num BETWEEN 1 AND 5 --top 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sum rest', SUM(theAmountSpent) FROM cte WHERE num > 5 -- sum of rest
```

Comment: This is certainly a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Another idea from Larsts code:

```
    WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT case 
              when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SUM(amount)) DESC) <=5 
                   then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SUM(amount)) DESC)
                   else 6 end AS num
        ,      groupName                                                               
        ,      SUM(amount) AS theAmountSpent
        FROM purchases
        GROUP BY groupName
    )
    SELECT num
    ,      max(groupName)
    ,      sum(theAmountSpent )
    FROM cte
    group by num
```